# Can I use socket.io without express in nuxt?

Tags: python, node.js, socket.io, nuxt.js

I want to graft socket.io on nuxt.  However, since I use python as a backend, I don't need to use express.

The server I'm using right now are the Web server (node) for real-time SSR, the backend server (python).

For WebSocket communication, I would like to run socket.io on a Web server (node).

Is this possible?

Comment: So you have a node server for SSR and python server for API? And you want to setup another node server for socket.io together with nuxt? If so then yes, it is possible in general...

Comment: Can I use a node server for SSR and a node server for socket.io at the same time? I'd like to use the same server.

Comment: The answer is yes is you setup socket.io instance in a different port via app.listen(<Port Number>);